# redis find key by value in serviceStack

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis, nosql

I Use ServiceStack C# for save and retrive data in Redis. I want find keys by value. try use SearchKey(string Pattern) for this opration, but not successful! 
code:

```
IList<City> ilstCity = RedisClient.SearchKeys("urn:City:babol");
Console.WriteLine(ilstCity[0].Title);
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a wild card if you're not doing an exact match, i.e:

```
RedisClient.SearchKeys("urn:City:babol*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scan command with Redis and match value to retrieve the key :

scan 0 MATCH *babol*

For serviceStack use : RedisClient.SCAN(0,0, *babol*)

For example usage check this : http://redis.io/commands/scan

**Note : However this is supported only from version Redis 2.8+**